# Network graph using R: Node size based on number of connected edges

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to see a size of the node/vertex based on number of connected edges. For example, if Node 1 has more number of connected edges with other nodes then size of Node 1 shall be larger. I have taken a hypothetical simple data and attempted network graph which is working fairly well. Basically, the network graph is about co-authorship network. However, I would like to adjust size of node based on number of connected edges. Also, I would like to know how can I customize color of edges?. For example, if Node 1 has more than 4 connections then color of all that 4 edges shall be red.

Following is the code which is doing well:

```
library(igraph)

# original data as a list
input_data  = list(c(1,2,3),c(1,4,5),c(1,6),c(3),c(4,6))

## function that makes all pairs
pairing <- function(x) {
  n = length(x)
  if (n<2) {
    res <- NULL
  } else {
  q <- combn(n,2)
  x2 <- x[q]
  #dim(x2) <- dim(q)
  res <- x2
  }
  return(res)
}

## for each paper create all author pairs
pairing_bypaper = lapply(input_data,pairing)

## remove papers that contribute no edges
pair_noedge = sapply(pairing_bypaper,is.null)
pair2_bypaper <- pairing_bypaper[!pair_noedge]

## combine all 'subgraphs'
pair_all <- do.call('c',pair2_bypaper)

## how many authors are there?
n.authors <- length(unique(pair_all))

## make a graph
my_graph = graph(pair_all, directed = FALSE)

## plot 
plot(my_graph)

plot(my_graph, vertex.label.cex = 0.8, edge.width = E(my_graph)$weight)
```

Thanks a lot in advanced.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First get the degree of your graph - a measure of how many points are connected to each vertex:

```
degree(my_graph)
[1] 5 2 2 3 2 2
```

We can then use this as the vertex size:

```
## size
V(my_graph)$vertex_degree <-  degree(my_graph)
```

And then in your plot call:

```
plot(my_graph, 
     vertex.label.cex = 0.8, 
     edge.width = E(my_graph)$weight, 
     vertex.size = V(my_graph)$vertex_degree #add this
     )
```

[image: Degree Graph]

If you want to scale this up or down, you could replace the above line with something like:

```
scale_factor <- 4
plot(my_graph, 
     vertex.label.cex = 0.8, 
     edge.width = E(my_graph)$weight, 
     vertex.size = V(my_graph)$vertex_degree * scale_factor
     )
```

Comment: Could also put the `degree()` call right into the `plot()` call and scale as you see fit: `plot(my_graph, vertex.size=degree(my_graph)); plot(my_graph, vertex.size=degree(my_graph)*3); plot(my_graph, vertex.size=degree(my_graph)^2)`

Comment: the returned object from the degree call is just a vector, so you could scale however you like (`^`, `log()`, ...)